# change const into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants

This is a slight expansion of the code CertainPerformance wrote here: [product of a sequence (factorial) javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469743/product-of-a-sequence-factorial-javascript)

This following code (see snippet) calculates consecutive products and keeps track of cummulative sums for 2 values of var b, but would become quite long if I were to add more numbers in the var b array and add more *cumsum* (e.g. *cumsum2*, *cumsum3*, ..) and *nHourCum* (e.g. *nHourCum2*, nHourCum3, ..)

I want to write *const cumsum* and *const nHourCum* as arrays. The idea is to avoid adding *cumsum1, cumsum 2*. I tried to write:

```
const cumsum = [cumsum0 + b[0] * nHour, cumsum0 + b[1] * nHour];
```

and similarly for nHourCum:

```
const nHourCum = [cumsum[0] + nHour, cumsum[1] + nHour]
```

instead of

```
const cumsum = cumsum0 + b[0] * nHour;
const cumsum1 = cumsum0 + b[1] * nHour;
const nHourCum = cumsum + nHour;
const nHourCum1 = cumsum1 + nHour;
```

but that method doesn't seem to work.

What did I do wrong with the const arrays?

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = [1000000, 2000000];
let time0 = 1; 
let cumsum0 = 0; 
for (var n = 2; n <= 96; n++) { 
  const nHour = time0 * (959 - 10*n)/(960 - 10*n) 
  const cumsum = cumsum0 + b[0] * nHour;
  const cumsum1 = cumsum0 + b[1] * nHour;
  const nHourCum = cumsum + nHour;
  const nHourCum1 = cumsum1 + nHour;
  if (n==2)
  {a.innerHTML += 'Hour ' + n + ': ' + b[0] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[0] + b[0] * nHour) + ' ---- ' + b[1] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[1] + b[1] * nHour) +'<br>';}
  else
  {a.innerHTML += 'Hour ' + n + ': ' + b[0] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[0] + nHourCum) + ' ---- ' + b[1] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[1] + nHourCum1) +'<br>';}
  time0 = nHour;
  cumsum0 = cumsum;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="a"></p> 
</body>
```

Comment: You do not have arrays (other than `b`) in your code.

Comment: The title makes no sense. `const` is part of a variable declaration that says in cannot be redeclared or reassigned. `const i = 0;` is valid and declares a variable `i` that is the number 0. How do you "change that to an array"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do this:

```
const a = document.getElementById("a");
const b = [1000000, 2000000];
let nHour, cumsum, nHourCum, time0 = 1, cumsum0 = 0;

for (let n = 2; n <= 96; n++) {
  nHour = time0 * (959 - 10 * n) / (960 - 10 * n);
  cumsum = [cumsum0 + b[0] * nHour, cumsum0 + b[1] * nHour];
  nHourCum = [cumsum[0] + nHour, cumsum[1] + nHour];

  if (n == 2) {
    a.innerHTML += 'Hour ' + n + ': ' + b[0] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[0] + b[0] * nHour) + ' ---- ' + b[1] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[1] + b[1] * nHour) + '<br>';
  } else {
    a.innerHTML += 'Hour ' + n + ': ' + b[0] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[0] + nHourCum[0]) + ' ---- ' + b[1] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[1] + nHourCum[1]) + '<br>';
  }
  time0 = nHour;
  cumsum0 = cumsum[0];
}
```

But I can't really see why. As pointed out in the comments under your post, you can't reassign or redeclare constants, however you can alter mutable objects even if they're assigned to constant variables. To be honest you'd be better of altering arrays than reassigning a variable with a new one every single loop:

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a");
const b = [1000000, 2000000];
const cumsum = [0, 0];
const nHourCum = [0, 0];
let time0 = 1, cumsum0 = 0, nHour;

for (let n = 2; n <= 96; n++) {
  nHour = time0 * (959 - 10 * n) / (960 - 10 * n);
  cumsum[0] = cumsum0 + b[0] * nHour;
  cumsum[1] = cumsum0 + b[1] * nHour;
  nHourCum[0] = cumsum[0] + nHour;
  nHourCum[1] = cumsum[1] + nHour;
  if (n == 2) {
    a.innerHTML += 'Hour ' + n + ': ' + b[0] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[0] + b[0] * nHour) + ' ---- ' + b[1] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[1] + b[1] * nHour) + '<br>';
  } else {
    a.innerHTML += 'Hour ' + n + ': ' + b[0] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[0] + nHourCum[0]) + ' ---- ' + b[1] * nHour + ' -- ' + (b[1] + nHourCum[1]) + '<br>';
  }
  time0 = nHour;
  cumsum0 = cumsum[0];
}
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
```